# Estimating the derivative of a polynomial on the unit circle

Tags: cv.complex-variables, polynomials

Let $P(z)=\sum_{k=0}^na_kz^k $ be a polynomial of degree $n$  and $z_k (1\leq k\leq n)$'s be $n$th roots of $-1$.  Then when $\theta=0$ the  inequality
$$|P'(e^{i\theta})|\leq \frac{4}{n}\left|\sum_{k=1}^nP(e^{i\theta}z_k)\frac{z_k}{(z_k-1)^2}\right|$$ does not hold.  Suppose we modify it as
$$|P'(e^{i\theta})|\leq \frac{4}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left|\frac{z_k}{(z_k-1)^2}\right| \max_{|z|=1}|P(z)|.$$
Is this modification true?

Comment: What is the summands in RHS corresponding to $z_k=1$?

Comment: This is wrong. Choose $P(z)=z^n+1$ and $\theta=0$. Then the RHS vanishes by construction. The LHS does not vanish since $P'(z)=nz^{n-1}$.

Comment: Numerical experiments suggest $$\sum_{k=1}^n\left\lvert\frac{z_k}{(z_k-1)^2}\right\rvert=\sum_{k=1}^n\left\lvert\frac{1}{(z_k-1)^2}\right\rvert=\frac{n^2}{4}.$$ This substitution transforms the statement into a [Theorem of Bernstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein%27s_theorem_(polynomials)).

Comment: @PhilippLampe: I suggest that you turn your comment into an answer, so that this question can be closed.

Answer (score 4):

Terms that are very similar to the terms given here can be found in an article by Aziz and Mohammad, see [[1](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1980-080-01/S0002-9939-1980-0574519-4/)].

Suppose that $a\neq -1$ is a complex number of modulus $1$. Let us denote the roots of the polynomial $z^n+a$ by $z_1,\ldots,z_n$. The authors show that
\begin{align*}
\left\lvert\frac{(1+a)^2}{na}\right\rvert\sum_{k=1}^n\left\lvert\frac{z_k}{(z_k-1)^2}\right\rvert=n.
\end{align*}
We put $a=1$. Then the right hand side in the considered inequality becomes $n\operatorname{max}_{\lvert z\rvert=1}\lvert P(z)\rvert$.

The desired inequality follows from a **Theorem of Bernstein**, see [2], which states $$\operatorname{max}_{\lvert z\rvert=1}\vert P'(z)\rvert \leq n\operatorname{max}_{\lvert z\rvert=1}\lvert P(z)\rvert.$$

1. A. Aziz and Q. G. Mohammad: [*Simple Proof of a Theorem of Erdős and Lax*](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1980-080-01/S0002-9939-1980-0574519-4/), Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. **80**, no. 1 (1980), 119--122
2. S. Bernstein: *Sur la limitation des dérivées des polynomes*, C. R. Math. Acad. Sci. Paris **190** (1930), 338--340